# Understand a microbenchmark for Cache/RAM access latency

Tags: performance, memory-management, benchmarking, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

In this picture:[pic](http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00538/bj4ibhaxypfz.jpg)

I don't really understand this plot. It basically shows the performance of reading and writing from different size array with different stride. Each color show different size of array. T know why it encrease but i don't know why it decrease?. So, for example for L (length of Array) = 64MB, and after stride=256k , why do you think time goes down again?

At this link, the code: [www.cs.berkeley.edu/~yelick/arvindk/t3d-isca95.ps](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~yelick/arvindk/t3d-isca95.ps)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper you posted tries to microbenchmark to find out the details of the Cray T3D. It reaches to the following conclusions:

- The cache line / block size is 32B
- The cache is direct mapped
- There is no L2 cache (just an L1)
- The page size is probably 8KB.

The next interesting remark is that *they surround the most inner loop of the experiment with another loop to repeat the experiment*. This loop actually enables caching.

Their code is the following:

```
for (arraySize = 4KB; arraySize < 8MB; arraySize *= 2)
   for (stride = 1; stride <= arraySize / 2; stride *= 2)
      for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i += stride)
         for (k = 0; k < repeats; k++)
            MEMORY_OPERATION_ON(A[i])
```

Let's take the arraySize = 4MB and strideSize = 1MB. You will access A[0], A[1M], A[2M], A[3M] each of them **repeats** times. That's only 4 addresses that will be cached easily.

So my theory is that **for larger strides, the number of actual addresses being read / written / updated is smaller**. This leads to 2 effects:

- You have less cache misses because you reuse the data stored at less addresses
- You have less TLB misses because you access less pages

I think that this is how the drops in latencies explains for larger strides.

For **small strides** the latency is low because you have higher chances of reading in the same cache block and there is also prefetching that might be more effective.

For **medium strides** you have enough reads to make caching ineffective, and because of the stride size you often get TLB misses because you jump through many pages. This gets to a higher latency.

My opinion is that this microbenchmarks should have been made on a fixed array size (8, 32 or 64MB) no matter the stride size, but large enough to reduce the caching effects. Higher the stride size higher the chances of reading the same address all over and over.

Comment: OK, Thanks (I don't have enough reputation for voting !),after preface you said: "for larger strides, the number of actual addresses being read / written / updated is smaller" , but Why and How?. and also you said :"My opinion is that this microbenchmarks should have been made on a fixed array size (8, 32 or 64MB) no matter the stride size." - Yes, The array size is fixed but the benchmark is done multiple time and each time for multiple size of stride (it means L= 1MB and S=1,2,4,8,16,... or L=2MB and S=1,2,4,8,16,...  just like what you have seen in the picture).

Comment: I didn't understand. For example for Array size=4MB and Stride=2MB, we will access A[0], A[2MB], A[4MB], A[6MB] because we jump over strides. So, That's only 4 addresses again!

Comment: @fidelroha how can you access A[6MB] when your array size is only 4MB? Consider your array size is 8MB and your stride size is 256B. How many addresses will you visit?

Comment: A[6MB] means the last element of the array (with considering strides among elements of array). You should consider length of the elements of array. If array size is 8 MB and stride is 256B, at each page we have:8kB(that is page size)/256B= 32 elements (from array) and we should access 8MB/8KB=1000 pages and so we have 1000*32=32000 addresses !?

Comment: @fidelroha. Yep. The lower the stride size, the reads in the array are more "dense". So if you have to read 32K addresses you will definetely have more cache misses then when reading only 4 addresses for larger strides.